# A weighted count of Egyptian fraction representations

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recreational-mathematics, egyptian-fractions

Given a positive rational $\alpha$ and a natural number $k$, let $N_k(\alpha)$ be the number of Egyptian fraction representations of $\alpha$ with smallest element ${1\over k}$ *(see e.g. the survey ["Paul Erdős and Egyptian Fractions"](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Eronspubs/13_03_Egyptian.pdf) by Graham)*. For $s>0$ let $$S_s(\alpha):=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}{N_k(\alpha)\over k^s}$$ and let $$t(\alpha)=\inf\{s: S_s(\alpha)<\infty\}.$$

My first question is what the above "threshold" value is, in at least one particular natural case:

> **Q1**: What is $t(1)$? Or, failing that, can we compute *any* concrete examples of $t(\alpha)$?

Tentatively, I suspect that $t(\alpha)=1$ for every positive rational $\alpha$, but I don't see how to prove that. Basically, I need an appropriate bound on the number of Egyptian fraction representations of a given rational with a given smallest term, but I don't see how to get a bound which is good enough for this question.

My second question is about what happens, specifically, at $s=2$:

> **Q2**: What is $S_2(1)$?

Comment: Can you show an upper or lower bound on your $t(\alpha)$? Probably a lower bound is easier. If you can show $N_k \geq 1$ for a positive density of $k$, for example, you would get $t(\alpha) \geq 1$, and this seems plausible. Also, I would guess you have a snowball's chance in hell of actually computing any nontrivial values of $S$, since the coefficients $N_k$ don't have any obvious nice properties.

Comment: To be honest I suspect that $t(\alpha)=\infty$ in all cases (there are simply so many Egyptian fraction representations!). This would follow if there were a lower bound for $N_k(\alpha)$ that was superpolynomial in $k$ (contrarily, $t(\alpha)=1$ would follow if there were a subpolynomial upper bound). I couldn't find this type of bound in the literature unfortunately.